# Ajax result is getting encoded

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, unicode

I have a page where onload I issue several POST requests simultaneously in order to load widgets on the page.  The request looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    success: function(htmlResult) {
        $div.html(htmlResult);
    }
})
```

Most of the time everything loads fine.  However, some of the time one of the widgets will get loaded with a [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Specials#Replacement_character).  It's not one specific widget that this happens to, but it could be any one of them at random.

When I inspect the bad HTTP response, I notice that the `Vary` header has a value of `Accept-Encoding` and the body is encoded.  All the other responses have a value of `*` for that header, and the body is text/html.  I'm not explicitly setting the `Vary` header value anywhere.

I can't figure out what's causing this random behavior.  Any ideas?

FYI, I'm posting to an ASP.NET MVC action, and returning a partial view.

Comment: can you try specifying the dataType?? the encoding happens by default when the browser accepts compression and the server can compress (usually gzip compression)...but its possbile that the encoding results in a bad transformation...json is usually utf-8

Answer (score 0):

have you tried dataType:'json' instead of 'html'?